# Proving differentiability of functions works in two ways

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently studying linear approximations of functions ($\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$) and reading about how to show the existence of a differential.

The book I am reading claims that you can show a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable through the definition of a derivative if and only if you can show it is differentiable through it's coordinate functions, such that $df(a)h = hf'(a)$.

This makes sense to me conceptually since the definition works from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and the coordinate derivatives work for more generalized functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. However, I'm trying to prove this statement and I'm having a bit of trouble. Given the limit of the definition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ exists, how can I generally show the coordinate functions in $\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable?

My problem might stem from the fact that I'm not quite understanding what the last statement $(df(a)h = hf'(a))$ is saying/means. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x+h) - f(x) = df(a) h + o(h)$ then taking the first coordinate:
$$
f_1(x+h) - f_1(x) =e_1 \cdot df(a) h + e_1\cdot o(h)
$$
and when $h\to 0$, 
$$
\frac{e_1\cdot o(h)}{h} = e_1\cdot \frac{ o(h)}{h} \to 0
$$
so 
$$
f_1(x+h) - f_1(x) =e_1 \cdot df(a) h + o(h)
$$
which implies that the first coordinate has a derivative, equal to $e_1 \cdot df(a)$.